# Why is my LayoutInflater not working in OnFling?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, onfling

I am trying to make it so that when I swipe from left to right on a listview item it will subtract one from a textview in my Customadapter. However, I can't get the LayoutInflater to work so I can access the TextView I need. I am able to do it in my onItemClick, but I can't get onfling to work. I added a toast notification to it to make sure it works (it does), but I can't get this piece of code to work.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    //identify the elemts we are using
    private ArrayAdapter aa;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Number> amount = new ArrayList<Number>();
    private ListView lv;
    private EditText et;
    private Button eom;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 75;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    GestureDetector gt;
    View.OnTouchListener gl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //assign values to the elements we are using
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.OneMoreList);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_om);
        eom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        gt = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());


        //onclick listener for the button to create a new OneMore
        eom.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = et.getText().toString();
                String skree = "One More " + s;    
                aa.add(skree);
                //notification of the data being sent, wipes the text, and closes the keyboard.
                et.setText("");
                hideSoftKeyboard();
            }
        });

        //defines the adapter we are using and sets it.
        aa = new OneMoreArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_count);
                String value = tv2.getText().toString();
                int n = Integer.valueOf(value);
                int nz = n + 1;
                String skr = Integer.toString(nz);
                tv2.setText(skr);
            }
        });

        lv.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gt.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });


    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            int pos = lv.pointToPosition((int)e1.getX(), (int)e1.getY());
            LayoutInflater inflator=MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final String[] listarray = new String[list.size()];
            list.toArray(listarray);



            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    //deletes
                    aa.remove(listarray[pos]);
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                //left to right
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){


                    final View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.one_more_list, null);
                    TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_count);
                    String value = tv2.getText().toString();
                    int n = Integer.valueOf(value);
                    int nz = n - 1;
                    String skr = Integer.toString(nz);
                    tv2.setText(skr);


                    //test to see if swipe works
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
class OneMoreArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private int[] colors = new int[]{R.color.Goldenrod, R.color.Crimson, R.color.ForestGreen};

    public OneMoreArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.one_more_list, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_more_list, parent, false);

        TextView tvtext = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_text);
        TextView tvcount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_count);

        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);

        final String[] listarray = new String[list.size()];
        list.toArray(listarray);


        tvtext.setText(listarray[position]);
        Number n = 0;
        String ns = n.toString();
        tvcount.setText(ns);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am really interested in figuring out why I am not able to access the TextView in the OnFling, and I would appreciate any nods in the right direction.

Comment: I think I can tell you why it's NOT working, but I don't know how easy it will be to fix it. Basically, in your onFling, you're inflating a NEW layout, one that never gets seen, not accessing the TextView that's already on screen. You can try not inflating a view and just calling "TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.layout_count);" ... but since all the listview rows should all have a textview with that id, I'm not sure there's any way to distinguish them.

Comment: You could TRY setting the GestureDetector in your adapter, after you inflate the view in the getView method. That way you can affect the count on the right list item. However, setting a listener on any of the views inside the list MIGHT interfere with the OnListItemClickListener being called. If it does, you could try moving your onListItemClicked code into an onClickListener in your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and insight! I look forward to trying it.